# Issue coding a program which makes a number with the even digits of an other number but backwards

Tags: php, string, numbers, equation

I have to make few coding blocks and I'm stuck at 3 of them. Sorry anticipated for my bad english.

First of all as said in summary. I tried this, it shows the even digits but also shows a tons of "0".

```
<?php

$n = 33421;
$m = "";

while ($n != 0) {
    if (($n % 2 == 0) && ($n / 10) != 0) {
        $temp = strval($n % 10);
        $m .= $temp;
    }
    $n = $n / 10;
}

echo $m;
?
```

And I have 2 other things to do but no clue how to get it done and hope can someone help.

[image: I don't really know how this is called in english]

[image: A system of equations with real numbers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to the problem which you show code for - to display even digits reversed.

This code first splits the number into individual elements using `str_split()` which takes a string and splits it into individual digits.  Then for each digit it checks if it is even and adds it to the start of the result (reversing the digits)...

```
$n = 33421;
$m = "";

foreach ( str_split($n) as $digit ) {
    if ( $digit % 2 == 0 )  {
        $m = $digit.$m;
    }
}
echo $m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a regex to remove all odds numbers and then reverse the output string.

```
$n = 33421;
$m = strrev(preg_replace("/[13579]/", "", $n));
echo $m; //24
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the str_split and foreach solution using preg_split and array_walk

```php
<?php
    /**
    * Split string into array
    * - walk the array and test values as multiples of 2
    * - pass $result by reference
    * - append $result after $value to reverse the resulting string
    */
    $number = 33421;
    $result = '';
    $arr = preg_split('//',$number,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    array_walk($arr, function(&$value) use (&$result) {
        if((int)$value % 2 == 0){
            $result = $value.$result; 
        }
    });
    echo $result;
?>
```